# SSIS data flow task executing before previous task completes its SQL operation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssis, transaction-isolation

In SSIS I have *DataFlowTask1* which will insert the data into `TABLE A`. The following data flow task will pull the data from `TABLE A`. But unfortunately, *DataFlowTask2* is getting fired before the *DataFlowTask1*  has completed inserting the data. Is there any commit happening? How should I ensure that the following data flow starts once the previous task has completed a SQL operation?

Also, what are TransactionOption and Isolation level properties in SSIS. Will any of these properties help solve my problem?

[image]

Comment: If your 'Precedence Constrain' arrow is set to `success` and is going from DFT1 to DFT2, then the second one should not start before the first one is completed successfully.

Comment: @TheEsisia Yes, I set the Value flag to Success. But it didn't work. Individual DFT work as expected. But they don't work when both are enabled

Comment: Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: Did you copy-paste any object between the two DFTs by any chance?

Comment: @TheEsisia - Yes a few data flow components within DFT1 into DFT2

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you said in your comments, I think this is what has happened: when you copy-paste objects from one `Data Flow Task` to another one in the same package, SSIS sometimes does not automatically assign to that object a new `ID`. So SSIS does not realize that they are two objects and therefore does not execute one before the other one. Two options:

1. Check the IDs of your objects (specifically the objects you have copied) See if they have same IDs.
2. Just do not copy-paste. Do everything by dragging and dropping brand new  objects.

Hope this helps.